# Specific word in Twitter account

Tags: twitter

I'm looking for a notification function in Twitter as the following:

When someone I FOLLOW tweets and his tweet has a specific word, I want to receive an email about that tweet. For example, I'm following XYZ and when his new tweet has "alert" word, I want to get notified by email in real time.

Is it possible?

Comment: ifttt.com might be able to do this.

Comment: You can use https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com for this.